# Accidentally renamed all files on desktop in windows 10 and they also got rearranged

Tags: file-recovery, batch-rename

I accidentally renamed all files on desktop in windows 10 and after that happened they all got rearranged and aligned to the left.

I don't have file history and don't have a restore point on this pc.

`Ctrl+Z` didn't do anything. When right clicking on the desktop I actually have `Redo New Ctrl + Y` option. Should I use it?

I don't want to just try it because I'm afraid it will cancel an option of something useful I could try now that might be gone when I try this one (something like a list of recently changed/renamed files).

What can I do?

does windows keep record of recently changed/renamed files?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Restore from your backup. You have backups, right? If not let this be a lesson ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm learning my lesson. What other backup methods are there except the ones I've mentioned I don't have?

Comment: A Restore point is not a backup solution for personal files.

Comment: @Moab - So what is?

And for all next commentators - I would appreciate if you'll write what can be done from now on for fixing the problem or what could've been done and not only what I've done wrong.

Comment: All I do is copy and paste the files to an external drive. Have 2 or more copies of critical files on different storage

Comment: ctrl/z is Undo & ctrl/Y is Redo, so if undo didn't work, that's it, out of options. How did you bulk rename? Maybe that tool has its own undo buffer?